# Cannot perform actions to geojson layer

Tags: leaflet

I have a geojson layer brought to my map window with ajax. I want to do an highlight action on the layer so it change color on mouseover. 
The thing is that I don't get the "hand with one pointing finger" to interact with the layer. Instead I get the "whole hand symbol" as if I was outside of my layer.

Does anyone have a general idea to why I don't get the hand with pointing finger when my pointer is over my layer?

My code for the highlighting action works (taken from the Interactive Choropleth example on the official leaflet site). If I copy my code to a new leaflet project it works fine. My leaflet project I want to use this code in is pretty big so i wont post it here, I am just out for some pointers if this is a common problem and where to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code it's just guessing: you might just have set `element.style` for your `cursor: inherit`, which can prevent your cursor from changing its state. (It may be done in css or js.)

Another option is that your layer is covered by other element, div, layer, ... If so you can play with layer's `z-index`.

For further answers please consider posting you code, even simplified version on codepen or jsfiddle.